# Indexing of DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've extracted data from a webpage by using pandas read_csv command. 
After extracting data I removed the first to row and converted column indexing. But when I try to convert index to date column I get an error every time. Following is the code.

```
    df=df.ix[2: , ]
    df.columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']
    #df=pd.DataFrame(df,index=df.ix[:,0])
    #df=pd.DataFrame(df,index='Date')
    #df=pd.DataFrame(df,index=df.ix[:,0], usecols=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']
```

I need a way out to make Date column as an index of DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else finds this seeking for a solution for a similar problem:
When using pandas read_csv command you can specify the column that will be used as index using the index_col method.

In the example below, the first column will be used as index:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col = 0)
```